# How to do a sort and a filter for a javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

if an object array has the following attributes type, age and gender eg

```
[{type: 0, age: 15, gender: "male"}, 
{type: 0, age: 16, gender: "female"}, 
{type: 0, age: 17, gender: "male"}]
```

what is the best way to do a filter and sort such that the object with the highest age (sort part) with type = 0 and gender= male (filter part) will be returned (in this instance `{type: 0, age: 17, gender: "male"}`)

so it first have to do a filter by type = 0 and gender = male
then do a sort to get the highest age for all objects that fit the criteria

Comment: what do you mean by  ***sort***?

Comment: sort based on age?

Comment: *what is the best way to do a filter and sort*? `array.filter` and `array.sort`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming, you want the oldest male with type equals zero, you could filter first and the sort by age descending. Take the first object as result.

```js
var array = [{type: 0, age: 15, gender: "male"}, {type: 0, age: 16, gender: "female"}, {type: 0, age: 17, gender: "male"}],
    result = array.filter(function (a) {
        return a.type === 0 && a.gender === 'male';
    });

result.sort(function (a, b) { return b.age - a.age; });
console.log(result[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the object with `type=0` and `max age`, you do not need to filter or sort.

Just loop through list and check if type is `0`, then compare age and return the one with max

**Note:** This is only applicable if you want to fetch one item. It can be scaled for few finite elements but not for generic number

```js
var array = [{type: 0, age: 15, gender: "male"}, {type: 0, age: 16, gender: "female"}, {type: 0, age: 17, gender: "male"}],
  result = array.reduce(function (p,c) {
    if(p.type === 0 && c.type === 0){
      return p.age > c.age ? p : c;
    }
    return p;
  });
console.log(result);
```